# Returning characters in single string lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not quite sure why this doesn't work, can anyone please help me fix this?

```
def valid(user_guess, valid_characters, guess_size):
    '''(list, str, int) -> bool
       Given a list of single character strS and a str, 
       return True if every character is in the given string.
     >>> (['A', 'C', 'B', 'E'], 'ACBE', 4)
     True
     >>> (['A', 'C', 'B', 'E'], 'ADFG', 4)
     False
    '''
    for char in user_guess:
        if char in valid_characters and len(user_guess) == guess_size:
            return True
        if char not in valid_characters and len(user_guess) != guess_size:
            return Fal
```

Comment: What should the function return when `char` "not in" `valid_characters` but `len(user_guess) == guess_size`?

Comment: Why `len(user_guess) == guess_size` and `len(user_guess) != guess_size` are inside the loop? these variables do not change!

Comment: For pure fun, try `valid(['E', 'T', 'W', 'Q'], 'ADFG', 4)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly more Pythonic way using [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)

```
def valid(user_guess, valid_characters, guess_size):
    return len(user_guess) == guess_size and all(c in valid_characters for c in user_guess)
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?  Error message, wrong answer, etc

Comment: It doesn't give me anything when I test it. I don't get a boolean. When I copy and paste the code I want to test, it just outputs the same code

Comment: Where are you doing the testing?  Try `valid(['A', 'C', 'B', 'E'], 'ACBE', 4)` after copying the code.

Comment: I'm doing it in wing 101 and I copied that code and I got the exact same code back after I tested it

Comment: I've never used wing.  [Here's a `repl`](https://repl.it/MsNj) showing this code in action.  If it's confusing you, it might be worth asking a question about your problem with wing.

Comment: I made an error by accident when I was copying my code into the shell. It works now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the `len(user_guess) == guess_size` condition is satisfied the `return True` is triggering after only checking the first `char`. For correctness, return `False` when this condition fails, and return `True` outside the loop if this never triggers.

Also, the length condition doesn't need to be evaluated inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure *exactly how* you want this code to work. However, based on your comment:

> Given a list of single character strS and a str, **return True
>     if every character is in the given string**.

I assume you simply want to know that **all** characters (="every character") in `user_guess` are in `valid_characters`. I would do it this way:

```
return len(set(user_guess).difference(valid_characters)) == 0
```

It is not clear what `guess_size` is supposed to do.

Answer (score -1):

This is one of many possible ways to valid the guesses

```
guesses = [(['A', 'C', 'B', 'E'], 'ACBE', 4),
           (['A', 'C', 'B', 'E'], 'ADFG', 4)]

def checkguess(g):
    chars = g[0]
    valid = g[1]
    guess_size = g[2]
    if chars == list(valid) and len(chars) == guess_size:
        return True
    else: 
        return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = [checkguess(g) for g in guesses]
    assert result == [True, False]
```